# In docker run, how to set multi-value in --ulimit

Tags: docker, ulimit

$ sudo docker run **--ulimit fsize=10240 cpu=12** -it ubuntu /bin/bash
docker: **Error parsing reference: "cpu=12" is not a valid repository/tag.
See 'docker run --help'.**

$ sudo docker run **--ulimit fsize=10240 --ulimit cpu=12** -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@ea4b00375adf:/# ulimit -a 
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0 
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
scheduling priority             (-e) 0 
file size               (blocks, -f) 10 
pending signals                 (-i) 5903
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524288
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) 12
max user processes              (-u) 524288
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

I want to set multi-value in --ulimit,

seems --ulimit fsize=10240 --ulimit cpu=12 works well,

but --ulimit fsize=10240 cpu=12 doesn't work,

is there any format I can use with only one --ulimit?

Comment: Repeating the `--ulimit` args is how to set multiple ulimit values, is there a reason you need to use only one? You can also limit CPU via `--cpuset-cpus="n"` but I assume you want to use ulimit.

Comment: When I search web for ulimit, I saw someone uses one --ulimit follows multi value, so I want to figure out whether it is ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ulimit tool shows blocks and not bytes.

Try:

```
sudo docker run --ulimit fsize=2048 --ulimit cpu=12 -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

ulimit -a

```
file size               (blocks, -f) 2
```